# Wordpress: How to use the_permalink() in sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't figure out a way to include a link to each post. When i insert

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read more</a>
```

the hole sidebar disappers. How do i use the_permalink()?

The "sidebar-right.php":

```
<div id="sidebar-right">

<div id="news">
<h1 class="news">Nyheter</h1>
<div class="border"></div>

<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?> 

<h2 class="news"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

//here I want the link

<?php endforeach; ?>


<div class="border"></div>

</div>

</div>
```

In the functions.php:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    return '...';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');


function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your PHP code. `<?php the_permalink() ?>` should work (the location of the first `?` question mark). Enable error logging so you can see if such a bare mistake happens. Asking here is not of much use.

Comment: I tried with the questionmark on the right place. When I wrote this question i placed it wrong. So that isn't the problem..

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

You are missing a semicolon.